# How can I determine the Unix account that a URL is associated with?

Tags: solaris, web

No documentation, keystone employee leaves ... All I have is the known URL that is called. How do I determine the account that executes this site so I can find the httpd.conf file and scripts?  Furthermore I have no access to the machine until I provide the account I need ... Catch 22, um I don't know the account.

The only thing going is the port number is a four digit non common number.
So I asked our admin to grep for this port number in all conf files but he claims there were only 2 hits and both irrelevant.

URL formatted like this ...
  https://mytestsite.company.com:4680/vendorXCBL

Is there a command I should have executed?  Or a file I should request?

Thanks for any insight.
Oh, and I'm new to Solaris and Unix.

Regards,   dan

Problem solved, I was given the wrong machine name, doh!  Everything falls together when I'm looking at the right machine.  Noobie shock syndrome.

Thanks for the response.

Comment: The port could be forwarded via DNAT to another port, so the system where the service should be running needs to be checked whether any process is using that port. If so, then it shouldn't be too hard for any capable admin to determine under what user that process is running, and what config is in use.